# httpd url rewrite rule configuration

Tags: linux, apache, administrator

My requirement is that I want to write a url rewrite rule such that if I open 
**http://localhost/google/** then it should open the **google.com** and if I open the **http://localhost/yahoo/** then it should open the **yahoo.com**.

Please suggest the required configuration in httpd configuration such that I can proceed with my business requirement.

Thanks in advance.

Nitesh

Comment: Did my answer work for you? Would a appreciate a short feedback :)

Answer (score 0):

Some additional information on your Apache version and if it is only required for those two URLs or should be a generic solution would be nice, but here is my suggestion for both:

This one is the most basic, just rewriting localhost/google to google.com and same for yahoo:

```
RewriteRule ^/(google|yahoo) https://$1.com/$2
```

Another option is to use a rewrite mapping file:

```
RewriteMap search txt:/etc/apache2/search.txt
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ ${search:$1} [R=permanent,L]
```

where the search.txt file should look something like this:

```
google  https://google.com
yahoo   https://yahoo.com
bing    https://bing.com
```

and so on...

Hopefully one of the versions will do the job for you :)

Best regards

Comment: Did it help or is some further help/clarification needed?